# How to emit 1's not closely followed by a 2

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

I have an observable stream which emits numbers, I want another stream that emits all 1's that are not closely followed by a 2 (within say 200ms), so for example from this source stream:

(every character is 100ms)

`1...12...112...11121...`

The result should be:

`..1.......1.....11...1.`

How would I do that using `rxjs@^6.6.7`?

Comment: You can't get the result you want. All `1` will have to be delayed by 200ms because you want to wait 200ms for `2` to emit.

Comment: That's harsh :) I don't think you're right, in fact I think I managed to do it, but I'll keep my solution to myself for now - I want to see if people can suggest better ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @martin's answer:

when a 1 is emitted,

- we create a new observable that waits for the next element for 200ms
- if no element comes within the 200msec, we emit the 1 and close the subscription
- if an element comes and it's a 2, we emit nothing and close the subscription
- if an element comes and it's a 1, we emit the original value and close the subscription

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-ihyznt?devtoolsheight=66&file=index.ts

```js
source
  .pipe(
    filter(value => value != 2),
    mergeMap(value =>
      source.pipe(
        first(),
        filter(v => v != 2),
        map(_ => value),
        timeout(200),
        catchError(_ => of(value))
      )
    )
  )
  .subscribe(value => console.log(value));
```

Comment: Very nice, similar to my own solution and possibly better, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/all-ones-not-closely-followed-by-a-two?file=index.ts - I use `race` with a `timer` but your `timeout` is more concise. Can we get rid of the `EMPTY` by using `filter` like in my stackblitz?

Comment: Actually I want only 1's so the first filter should be `value == 1` like before

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this. Each `1` is wrapped with an inner Observable and delayed by 200ms which might be completed earlier using `takeUntil()` and thus ignored:

```
source$
  .pipe(
    filter(value => value === 1),
    mergeMap(value => of(value).pipe(
      delay(200),
      takeUntil(source$.pipe(
        filter(value => value === 2),
      )),
    )),
  )
```

Comment: Wouldn't this drop all 1's if a 2 occurred within 200ms of the first? A 2 should only cause at most one 1 to be dropped.

Comment: This will drop all `1`s that are followed by `2` within 200ms.